# App Engine, Jetty, GWT(GXT) projects, reduce the free space on my disk

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty

I installed:

On disk “D”:
WinXP SP3

On disk “E”:
JDK 1.7.0_10,
Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, 
GWT 2.4, GXT 2.2.5, 
App Engine 1.7.0, 
Glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows-ml,

Also, I have paths:

```
D:\Windows
E:\Eclipse\
E:\MyGwtProjects\
```

When I try to run my web applications in development mode(AppEngine,Jetty):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/Files.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

I have the side effect – the free space on my disk “D” became smaller and smaller. **Where I can find the files of my temporary projects on disk “D” to delete them?**

When I used Glassfish I could delete all files in the:

```
E:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gwt temp files are usually located in Temp folder support.microsoft.com/kb/92635.You can use disk clean up feature of windows once in a while or automate disk clean up via batch file.

Comment: Thank you, I've already found this folder (there was ~14Gb): D:\Documents and Settings\MyUser\Local Settings\Temp\